# Does TCL statements come under implicit cursors?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, cursor

Does TCL statements come under implicit cursors if they are not declared explicitly? [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/sql_cursor.htm#LNPLS01348). Or is `COMMIT` a PL/SQL statement?

> A SQL (implicit) cursor is opened by the database to process each SQL statement that is not associated with an explicit cursor.

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
row_var test%rowtype;
BEGIN
savepoint a;
execute immediate 'delete from test';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No. of deleted '||sql%rowcount);
if (sql%rowcount=0) then  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CP1:');
end if;
/*Select * into row_var from test;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No. of after delete '||row_var.testcol);*/
commit; //TCL statment
END;


Select * from test
```

Answer (score 0):

COMMIT is part of the SQL language. [SQL Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm)

"Use the COMMIT statement to end your current transaction and make permanent all changes performed in the transaction. A transaction is a sequence of SQL statements that Oracle Database treats as a single unit. This statement also erases all savepoints in the transaction and releases transaction locks."

And can be invoked in a PL/SQL block as a static SQL statement. [PL/SQL Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/commit_statement.htm)

"The COMMIT statement makes permanent any changes made to the database during the current transaction. A commit also makes the changes visible to other users....The SQL COMMIT statement can be embedded as static SQL in PL/SQL."